# Why line returns are not reapply after doing esc_sql?

Tags: sql

I trying show data from my database. This data was escape by esc_sql like bellow.

But when I use it in `echo`, line-returns are print as *normal* chars ('\', 'r', '\', 'n').

```
$data = esc_sql("
    sample data with line returns
");

echo $data; // Output = \r\n    sample data with line returns\r\n
```

What is the best way to re-apply line returns after doing esc_sql ?

Comment: esc_sql is for values you're passing in to the database, not values taken from the database to display. You should escape them for HTML instead.

Comment: I use esc_sql only before insert but when I access it by a `wpdb->get_results` the result is same

Comment: Sorry I misspoke: esc_sql is for values you're concatenating into SQL statements. Which you shouldn't be doing unless you absolutely have to. It's not for values you're passing into the database any other way e.g. parameterised statements (which is how you should be doing it). You probably don't need to esc_sql the values.

Comment: As i can see [here (esc_sql() | Function)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/) on `BasicExample` values are escape too

Comment: Yes, but they're being assembled into the SQL SELECT statement string. You're not doing that to insert data are you?

Comment: You should use `wpdb->prepare` not `esc_sql` to prepare variables safely for SQL queries, never `esc_sql`. If you are using `wpdb->insert` or `wpdb->update` this is done for you. `esc_sql` does not do what you think it does, you should not be using it

Comment: Insertions of data are also at risk without using prepared statement. [SQL Injection in Different Statement Types](https://portswigger.net/support/sql-injection-in-different-statement-types). I should be use as you say `wpdb->prepare`.

Comment: `esc_sql` is not how you prepare a query in WordPress, `$wpdb->prepare` is how you prepare an SQL query

Comment: Thanks ! Last question do you know if `$wpdb->insert` implement same verification as prepared statement ?

Comment: @AdrienVillalonga these are the comments not the solutions, I posted an answer below, but all of this is covered in great detail with examples in the official WordPress documentation e.g.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#insert-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what `esc_sql` is for, or what it should be used for.

### Safely Escaping Variables In SQL Queries

To make variables safe for an SQL query, use `$wpdb->prepare`, e.g.

```php
$table_name = "{$wpdb->prefix}myTable";
$myID = 12;
 
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE `$table_name` SET `your_column_1` = 1 WHERE `$table_name`.`your_column_id` = %d",
        $myID
    )
);
```

Notice that `$myID` is safely inserted into the SQL query using `$wpdb->prepare`, and is not directly included in the query string. `esc_sql` is not used here.

### Safely Escaping Query Results

To escape data you have retrieved from the database on output, use the function that matches the context it's being displayed in

- `esc_html` for non-HTML text
- `esc_attr` for HTML tag attributes
- `esc_url` for URLs
- `wp_kses_post` for content with tags allowed in post content

### When Should I Use `esc_sql`?

Very, very, rarely:

> Usually you should prepare queries using wpdb::prepare(). Sometimes, spot-escaping is required or useful. One example is preparing an array for use in an IN clause.

and

> Be careful in using this function correctly. It will only escape values to be used in strings in the query. That is, it only provides escaping for values that will be within quotes in the SQL (as in field = '{$escaped_value}'). If your value is not going to be within quotes, your code will still be vulnerable to SQL injection. For example, this is vulnerable, because the escaped value is not surrounded by quotes in the SQL query: ORDER BY {$escaped_value}. As such, this function does not escape unquoted numeric values, field names, or SQL keywords.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/

Most WP developers will never use or encounter `esc_sql` and that's a good thing.

Comment: Thank you for all these precisions 